# VPN Client kills all connection while disconnecting

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, cisco, windows-vista

When my VPN Client (5.0.0.3) connection is lost after being idle OR I force it to disconnect when switching between my Colo and Office it always knocks out my normal connection for a second.

I'll notice it because my IM client disconnects then reconnects.  It never did this to me in XP, but seems to be a problem in Vista / Server 2008.  It's more annoying when I'm streaming music/video and have to pause/restart it.

Has anyone else noticed this and found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried 5.0.04.0300 or the new version 5.0.05.0290?

Comment: What a silly idea :P YES, it worked using 5.0.0.4.0300!  I don't get any dropped pings when disconnecting.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Cisco VPN client is notoriously buggy on Vista.  If it's possible, I would recommend the AnyConnect client instead of the fat client.

Comment: I wish I could, but we're using PIX rather than ASA. I'm tempted to test out Windows 7 to see if it's any better.

Comment: Is there a chance they could initiate split tunneling as opposed to full tunneling?

Comment: @GregD - Yes, we have split tunneling enabled for bandwidth reasons.  I'm going to give Windows 7 a shot and report back.